# Meteor - Flowrouter: generic vs variable route

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I want to display posts for different cities, defined by `cityId`:

```
FlowRouter.route("/:cityId", {
   name: 'postList',
   action: function() {
      console.log(FlowRouter.getParam("cityId"));
      return BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', {
        top: 'header',
        body: 'postList'
      });
    }
});
```

Alongside with that I of course have generic routes like 'admin', 'signup' and so on.
But when I go to `/signup`, the `postList` route gets activated, treating 'signup' word as a city id, and 'signup' is logged in console.
Defining route like `FlowRouter.route("/postList/:cityId")` is not an option.

Comment: 'Defining route like FlowRouter.route("/postList/:cityId") is not an option.' Unfortunately, it's your only option. Just make a `/city/:cityId` route.

Comment: If you make everything after / a variable, the route "/:cityId" will evaluate to true every time. The only other idea I have is to create a route like "/pages/signup" to see if the second slash causes it to not evaluate that route as a "/:cityId" route.

Comment: @BrettMcLain, yep, that solution works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to control route definition order.
[`define the /signup route before the generic one: /:cityId`](https://forums.meteor.com/t/flowrouter-generic-vs-variable-route/15984/18)